# Bot Telegram em Python "quebra" após primeira consulta

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Preciso de uma ajuda pra resolver um problema em um bot para Telegram em Python que após receber uma segunda consulta "quebra"; para de funcionar. Talvez esse código tenha muitos "erros" aos olhos de desenvolvedores experientes, não tenho muito conhecimento. Estou aprendendo e agradeço qualquer dica ou sugestão.

```
import pymysql.cursors
import telebot

CHAVE_API = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(CHAVE_API)


conn = pymysql.connect(
    host= 'xxxxxxxx',
    user= 'xxxx',
    passwd= 'xxxx',
    database= 'xxxx'
)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(mensagem):
    first_name = mensagem.chat.first_name
    bot.reply_to(mensagem, "Olá *"+first_name+"*, tudo bem?\n\nEsse bot faz consulta das informações físicas dos nodes. Para iniciar clique no comando abaixo:\n\n /node", parse_mode='markdown')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["node"])
def node(mensagem):
    first_name = mensagem.chat.first_name
    bot.reply_to(mensagem, "Digite o nome do node.")


def verificar(mensagem):
    return True

@bot.message_handler(func=verificar)
def responder(mensagem):
    msg = mensagem.text.upper()
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = f"SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE nome_novo LIKE '{msg}'"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            
            if result:
                nome_novo = result[2]
                nome_antigo = result[1]
                rx1 = str(result[3])
                rx2 = str(result[6])
                rx3 = str(result[9])
                rx4 = str(result[12])
                tx1 = str(result[15])
                tx2 = str(result[18])
                tx3 = str(result[21])
                tx4 = str(result[24])
                adc = str(result[27])
                hv = str(result[29])
                site = (result[30].capitalize())
                cidade = result[31]
                bot.send_message(mensagem.chat.id, nome_novo+" ("+nome_antigo+")\n\nRX: "+rx1+" - "+rx2+" - "+rx3+" - "+rx4+"\nTX: "+tx1+" - "+tx2+" - "+tx3+" - "+tx4+"\nDGO: "+adc+"\nHV: "+hv+"\nSite: "+site+" / "+cidade)
            else:
                bot.send_message(mensagem.chat.id, "Node não encontrado!")

bot.polling()
```

[image: Imagem do Telegram enviando a primeira mensagem e recebendo a resposta, depois não recebe resposta da segunda mensagem]

[image: Imagem do erro no terminal do vs code]

Comment: isso acontece porque você usa o with para chamar a conexão, o with fecha automaticamente o recurso no fim do processo, então na primeira vez dá certo, mas na segunda, quando você chama novamente a conexão ela já está fechada e esse erro ocorre

Comment: Perfeito! Resolvido. Obrigado Lucas Miranda.